# Excel trend lines to c# code error?

Tags: c#, excel

I've converted the following expression

[image]

to this function

```
private double getRisingTemp(double x/*time*/)
{
    double y;
    y = Math.Pow(3 * 10, -12) * Math.Pow(x, 5) - Math.Pow(4 * 10, -9) * Math.Pow(x, 4) + Math.Pow(10, -6) * Math.Pow(x, 3) + 0.0005 * Math.Pow(x, 2) - 0.0302 * x + 23.826;
        return y;
}
```

But the graph in `C#` looks a bit different from the one I see in Excel. Just want to make sure my C# function 100% corresponds to equation.

[image]

[image]

If function is fine, what might be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expressions for the x^4 and x^5 coefficients are incorrect. Just use the built in `double` with scientific notation:

```
y = 3e-12 * Math.Pow(x, 5) - 4e-9 * Math.Pow(x, 4) + 1e-6 * Math.Pow(x, 3) + 0.0005 * Math.Pow(x, 2) - 0.0302 * x + 23.826;
```

Comment: +1 for scientific notation. Forgot about it when formatted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to review the documentation on `Math.Pow()`, which can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow.aspx). For example your first conversion is wrong: `Math.Pow(3 * 10, -12)` and doesn't correspond to your: 3E-12. What `3E-12` means is 3 times 10 to the 12th. You can read more about this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6273/what-does-e-mean-in-9-0122222900391e-5).

Hope this helps you!

Comment: so it could have been `3 * Math.Pow(10, -12)`